# Slowdown when using Mutect2 container inside Nextflow

Tags: bioinformatics, nextflow

I'm trying to run MuTect2 on a sample, which on my machine using java takes about 27 minutes to run.

If I use virtually the same code, but inside Nextflow and using the GATK3:3.6 docker container to run Mutect, it takes 7 minutes longer, for seemingly no apparent reason.

Running on Ubuntu 18.04, the tumor and normal samples are from an Oncomine panel. Tumor is 4.1G, normal is 1.1G. I thought the time might be spent copying in data to the container, but 7-8 minutes seems far too long for that. Could it be from copying in reference files too?

`bai_ch` is the channel that brings in the tumor and normal index files

```
process MuTect2 {
  label 'mutect'

  stageInMode 'copy'
  publishDir './output', mode : 'copy', overwrite : true

  input:
  file tumor_bam_mu from tumor_mu
  file normal_bam_mu from normal_mu
  file "*" from bai_ch
  file mutect2_ref
  file ref_index from ref_fasta_i_m
  file ref_dict from Channel.fromPath(params.ref_fast_dict)
  file regions_file from Channel.fromPath(params.regions)
  file cosmic_vcf from Channel.fromPath(params.cosmic_vcf)
  file dbsnp_vcf from Channel.fromPath(params.dbsnp_vcf)
  file normal_vcf from Channel.fromPath(params.normal_vcf)

  output:
  file '*' into mutect_ch

  script:
  """
  ls
  echo MuTect2 task path: \$PWD
  java -jar /usr/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
    --analysis_type MuTect2 \
    --reference_sequence hg19.fa \
    -L designed.bed \
    --normal_panel normal_panel.vcf \
    --cosmic Cosmic.vcf \
    --dbsnp dbsnp.vcf \
    --input_file:tumor $tumor_bam_mu \
    -o mutect2.somatic.unfiltered.vcf \
    --input_file:normal $normal_bam_mu \
    --max_alt_allele_in_normal_fraction 0.1 \
    --minPruning 10 \
    --kmerSize 60
  """

}
```

My only thought is to create my own docker that has the reference files handy, which will probably save time for copying them in? I'd expect the nextflow+container version to run only slightly slower than the CLI version.

Answer (score 1):

Check the task Bash wrapper in the task work dir to asses the performance issue.